# Does voice-acting go through an editing process?

Tags: editing, voice-acting

I recently watched the live voice-acting (dubbing) for a foreign animated movie.

The voice-actors were sometimes reading their lines wrong or with a little bloopers, and they were re-reading every time they had mistakes.

My question is, does voice-acting like cinema go through an editing process to delete the unwanted parts (after finishing the work), or they just cut and delete the mistakes at the same time they are voice-acting and repeat the lines?

Comment: More former but both

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Bear in mind the sound recordists aren't limited to a single recording track, like an old tape machine. They have literally as many tracks as they need, all on computer, using such as [Protools](https://www.avid.com/pro-tools/audio-post), [Logic](https://www.apple.com/uk/logic-pro/) or [Nuendo](https://www.steinberg.net/nuendo/).

So they are free to do as many different versions as they need, all synchronised to the video playback.
From these separate tracks then can then make a composite of the best bits, by simply selectively muting the others.

Once they're happy with this, they can then re-time any sections that don't quite match the lip-sync using software such as [VocAlign](https://www.synchroarts.com/products/vocalign-ultra/overview) (which has been around since the late 90s) or [Revoice](https://www.synchroarts.com/products/revoice-pro/overview).